# Can we omit "the" in poems even if it makes the sentence nonsensical?

Tags: creative-writing, poetry

Can we omit "the" in poems even if it makes the sentence nonsensical?

For example:

> They remembered the taste of fruits they enjoy.

instead of:

> They remembered the taste of the fruits they enjoy.

and

> They love the light of kerosene lamps

instead of:

> They love the light of the kerosene lamps

Even if we're referring to specific lamps and fruits.

When is it permitted to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you can do anything in poetry. Some would say that's the definition of poetry. Much poetry isn't Standard English. Try reading people like e e cummings.

It is definitely permissible to leave out 'the'. However, the two examples you give are 'correct' English as they are. Though, they don't refer to specific lamps and fruits.

Answer (score 2):

Permitted? As in a classroom setting?

Even then the teacher will likely give a lot of latitude regarding the "rules".

Otherwise as said by @S. Mitchell, you can do whatever you want. In poetry,  grammar is just a guideline, a suggestion really, and the poem is often stronger by not being "correct".

> Poe-teary is war roles: break "fast" is a most: Beauty! is imperfect, non- , grand mare is death: Ahum .

Since you asked about getting rid of those "the", I would suggest going further and getting rid of the gaggle of they, the, the... To me, those are unsavory, unnecessary, mouthfuls.

For example:

> Memories of fruit's tasting

Or

> Remembrance of fruit's taste

instead of:

> They remembered the taste of fruits they enjoy.

and

> Love of the kerosene lamps' light

Or

> Lovely kerosene lamps' glow

Or if these are part of the same poem, I would destructure the sentences

> Remembering

> Love
>
> Enjoying

> Fruits' taste
>
> Glow
>
> Kerosene lamps

Though I admit these modifications change the meaning a bit.